# Parsing nested key from dict (generated from json)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am looking at anisble python API, which returns values via json, which can then be stored as dict

```
{
"dark" : {
   "web1.example.com" : "failure message"
},
"contacted" : {
   "web2.example.com" : 1
}
}
```

I finding it a challenge to dict.get the nested value, of web2.example.com, under contacted.

Thanks in advance. I would give my examples, but they are failing to provide anything usable.

Reference:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/12a2585e84be7fdf40e07ca1415f4938e95de1f3/docsite/rst/developing_api.rst

Comment: `import json` and `json.loads('{"key" : 5}')` or `json.dumps({1 : 5})`.

Comment: Have you already loaded the JSON into a Python dictionary? Nested dictionaries are no different from regular dictionaries; once you reference the nested object via `python_dictionary['concacted']`, you have that nested dictionary. You can then do things like loop over it to access all the keys, or use `dict.items()` or `dict.values()` to get the `(key, value)` pairs or just all the values.

Comment: So use python_dictionary['concacted'] and then what  would I use to get the first nested key from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you get dictionary as follow :-

```
dictFromJSON = {
"dark" : {
   "web1.example.com" : "failure message"
},
"contacted" : {
   "web2.example.com" : 1
}
}
```

Then you can access values as follow :--

```
for strKey, dictVal in dictFromJSON.items():
    if strKey == "contacted":
       print dictVal.keys()
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I don't know what the value of 'web1.example.com' is. This is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: It'll give you "failure message" as in the example given above.

Comment: I don't want failure message, I want the hostname, and nothing else that follows.

Comment: I have changed the answer. Check it out, if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! Much closer now, only thing is it returns the dark key as well ['web1.example.com']
['web2.example.com']

Is there anyway of only getting the nested key from 'contacted'?

Comment: Check it out, if it serves your purpose.